# Is there a way to modify IntelliJ's 'Select In' dialogue?

Tags: intellij-idea

There's a "Select in" dialogue in IntelliJ IDEA which is launched by <kbd>Alt+F1</kbd>. It is very useful and it looks like this:
[image: Select in screenshot]

Is there any way to change the shortcuts in it? For example, what if i want to launch "Show in Explorer" by pressing <kbd>6</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet, please [vote for the open issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-83989) in YouTrack.